# onListItemClick not working in Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, list, onclicklistener

I have a listView in my project and i am assigning onListitemClick listener for it.

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and i am giving the listener as:

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.i("CLICK", "onListItemClick");

}
```

The click action is working fine in Android 2.2+ devices except for Android 4.1.2 device. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: May be your list have focusable items like buttons, checkboxes, radio button etc..They make the listview lose its focus and not clickable..show your complete code to let us understand yoru problem

Comment: refer this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138716/in-listview-when-list-item-has-button-onlistitemclick-doesnt-work ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531404/android-onitemclicklistener-event-not-fired-when-page-is-swipped-fragmentactiv ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352486/cant-click-on-items-in-listview-with-custom-adapter

Comment: probably the event is being consumed by some other view, post your layout xmls, both activity and list Item

Answer (score 4):

Can you jut replace Listner.

use:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.d("^^^^^^^", "position="+arg2);

    }
```

Instead:

```
 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.i("CLICK", "onListItemClick");

}
```

Another way:

it seem listview is block due to row file, use below property within row file main layout.

> android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"